# EF Code First Many to Many mapping using existing mapping class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have three classes

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class ProductXUser // Mapping class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    public int Product_Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateMapped { get; set; }
}
```

How can i map a many to many relationship (using Fluent API) between `User` class and `Product` class using `ProductXUser` class as the mapping table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Once you expose junction table as entity you cannot use many-to-many relation. You must instead use two one-to-many relations. One from `User` to `ProductXUser` and second from `Product` to `ProductXUser`. You must also change navigation properties in both `Product` and `User` to point to collection of `ProductXUser`. Direct many-to-many relation works only when you do not expose junction table as an entity.